# Can't get Django localization to work

Tags: python, django, locale

I've searched several threads and bug reports, but couldn't find a solution.

I changed the locale of my Django project to `pt-br` but it made no difference. I excepted all input fields and outputs to localize dates and numbers, specially `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR` and `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR`, including in the admin API. But the dates there continue to appear as `yyyy-mm-dd` and decimal separator "," generates an error upon input.

I did everything I found: changed the settings, added localization middleware classes, enabled USE_I18N and USE_L10N, tried to force setlocale manually, etc. Here is a glimpse of my settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
)

DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'd/m/Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%Y-%m-%d')
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = ','
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = '.'
```

Is it weird that my Python console running on a Brazilian Portuguese Windows outputs this?

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('pt_BR', 'cp1252'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python25\lib\locale.py", line 478, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Any ideas of what I forgot to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows uses different locale IDs.  The following should work (obtained from the table on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb895996.aspx)):

```
In [15]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'Portuguese_Brazil')
Out[15]: 'Portuguese_Brazil.1252'
```

Comment: Well, setlocale did work, but it didn't change any behaviour in Django.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Django Track](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16452), `INPUT_FORMATS` setting is ignored if `USE_L10N` is set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit OT, but I wanted to add my view on web translation.

I strongly recommend using [Bablic](http://www.bablic.com). It's a completely client-side approach to translation. They track the strings that are displayed on your site, build the "dictionary", and notify you of new or untranslated text. They can also integrated with cloud based translation providers so that even newly submitted content will be translated almost immediately without need for you tracking or making any updates to the server-side code or configuration.

I love it that you don't need to do the whole collect-strings->send-mo-file-to-translators->compile->deploy->debug->repeat. And as a web-dev this solution has zero friction on my end.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases is not enable on server and you need run this command to enable locale (in my server Ubuntu example)

```
sudo locale-gen pt_BR
```

And then run

```
python -c "import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR')"
```